# What is probability density function in the context of scipy.stats.norm?

Tags: scipy, probability-density

This is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find a good answer. What exactly does scipy calculate for

```
scipy.stats.norm(50,10).pdf(45)
```

I understand that the probability of a particular value like 45 in a gaussian with mean 50 and std dev 10 is 0. So what exactly is pdf calculating? Is it the area under the gaussian curve, and if so, what is the range of values on the x axis?

Comment: Interesting question, but not at all a programming question. You may want to start with this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: The question "What is a probability density function?" should be asked over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In fact, it has already been asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-is-a-density-function

Comment: You said that "probability of a particular value like 45 in a gaussian with mean 50 and std dev 10 is 0". But to me it is not 0, but a float value AND running the line of code you get: `0.03520653267642995`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) expressed in Python is

```
from math import pi
from math import exp
from scipy import stats


def normal_pdf(x, mu, sigma):
    return 1.0 / (sigma * (2.0 * pi)**(1/2)) * exp(-1.0 * (x - mu)**2 / (2.0 * (sigma**2)))
```

(compare that to the wikipedia definition). And this is exactly what `scipy.stats.norm().pdf()` computes: the **value** of the pdf at point `x` for a given `mu, sigma`.

Note that this is **not** a probability (= **area** under the pdf) but rather the *value* of the pdf at the point `x` you pass to `pdf(x)` (and that value can very well be greater than `1.0`!). You can see that, for example,  for `N(0, 0.1)` at `x = 0`:

```
val = stats.norm(0, 0.1).pdf(0)

print(val)

val = normal_pdf(0, 0, 0.1)

print(val)
```

which gives the output

> 3.98942280401
>
> 3.989422804014327

Not at all a probability = area under the curve!

Note that this doesn't contradict the statement that the probability of particular value like `x = 0` is `0` because, formally, the area under the pdf for a point (i.e., an interval of length `0`) is zero (if **f** is a continuous function on [a, b] and **F** is its antiderivative on [a, b], then the definite integral of **f** over [a, b] = **F(a) - F(b)**. Here, `a = b = x` hence the value of the integral is `F(x) - F(x) = 0`).

Answer (score 1):

what you are getting is pdf at value x for a normal pdf function
with mean 50 and standard deviation 10.
[check the function here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution))

easy to visualize using

```
npdf=norm(50,10)
plt.plot(range(0,100), npdf.pdf(range(0,100)), 'k-', lw=2)`
```

you could also generate random variables from the normal pdf you created using

```
npdf.rvs(1000) #1000 numbers 
hist=plt.hist(n.rvs(10000),bins=100,normed=True)
```

[theoretical pdf and normalized histogram from random variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktOI4.png)

Comment: Thanks - but I am still not clear on how exactly the pdf is calculated at value x. Is there a range x - delta, x + delta used to calculate the area under the normal distribution? If so, what is the delta used?